# Wildfly 10 doesnt use my log4j.xml in my jar inside an ear

Tags: java, logging, log4j, ejb, wildfly

I deployed my **.ear**(including a war and a jar) on my **wildfly 10.1.0** server successfully. The jar-module doesn't write any logs, while the .war writes logs just fine.

So this is what I see when I click on view for the deployment in the **wildfly-webgui**:

```
-> subdeployment -> xy.war -> subsystem -> logging -> config -> classpath to log4j.xml

-> subdeployment -> xy.jar -> subsystem -> logging -> config -> default
```

I built the .ear with **maven** and both modules have the same **log4j.xml** (just a different path for saving the log).

```
The xy.war log4j.xml classpath is WEBINF -> Classes -> log4j.xml.

The xy.jar log4j.xml classpath is /log4j.xml.
```

I am superuser, but whenever I try to edit the `logging->configuration` to add the classpath additionally to the default config, wildfly tells me:

```
You seem to lack permissions to add new resources.
```

Any ideas how to make **wildfly** use my **log4j.xml** in the **jar**?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** The jar is an EJB-Module

**Edit 2 (Solved it!):**
**If you want to use the same logging configuration for the web deployment and the EJB try adding the log4j.xml to EAR/META-INF/log4j.xml.**

Comment: Where do you use the jar? Is it an ejb module?

Comment: Yes it is an ejb module!

Comment: What configuration is the ejb modul using? None at all? Or a wrong one? Would it be possible to enable log4j debug? JVM property named log4j.debug or  log4j2.debug shall do it.

Comment: If you want to use the same logging configuration for the web deployment and the EJB try adding the log4j.xml to `EAR/META-INF/log4j.xml`.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Thank you so much! I always tried to add the log4j.xml into the resource directory from EAR.... it worked adding it to the EAR/META-INF! Thank you sir!